# Connecting to the MySQL Database using Dependency Injection in PHP

Tags: php

I am currently trying to grasp the basics of Dependency Injection and I'm running into quite a bit of trouble.

While I do understand the basic premise of why it's useful (ease of unit testing, removal of hard-coded classes), I don't really understand how that goes into databases.

Basically, I cannot for the life of me understand how I can connect to a database using the DI technique.

As far as I understand I would have to pass all variables through a constructor

```
Class DatabaseConfiguration
{
    private $servername;
    private $dbname;
    private $dbuser;
    private $dbpass;

    public function __construct(string $server, string $name, string $user, 
    string $pass, string $charset){
        $this->servername = $server;
        $this->dbname = $name;
        $this->dbuser = $user;
        $this->dbpass = $pass;
        $this->dbcharset = $charset;
}
```

This is where I get stuck. I am quite clueless on what I should be doing next to establish a connection.

Usually, I would hard-code the values and then call a function in which I would do something like this:

```
public function connectDB(){
    try{
        $conn = "mysql:host=".$this->servername.";dbname=".$this->dbname.";charset=".$this->dbcharset;
        $pdo = new PDO($conn, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $pdo;
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "Connection failed: ".$e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

I have no clue how to do it the DI way, though.

Comment: Your `DatabaseConfiguration` class doesn't appear to serve much of a purpose. If it read configuration from a file (for example) then it would be more useful but as it stands, you might as well just establish your `PDO` instance without it

Comment: As for DI, I'm not seeing much of that in your question yet. What you would typically do with a DB connection is create **one** (ie `new PDO(...)`) and inject it where required, eg `class SomethingRepository { private $conn; public function __construct(PDO $conn) { $this->conn = $conn; } }`

Comment: I'm sure you aren't because it's probably not there as I'm trying to grasp the basics of it but seems like I'm even more lost than I originally thought...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comments above, [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) involves passing objects to other classes where required.

For example, say you had some *model* class that requires a database connection. One option is to *inject* a `PDO` instance into the constructor, eg

```
class UserModel {
    private $conn;

    public function __construct(PDO $conn) { // injected here
        $this->conn = $conn;
    }
```

In the above, the `UserModel` knows only that it has a `PDO` instance available to it. It does not know anything about the connection details or configuration, nor should it have to.

You would then use it like this...

```
$conn = new PDO(
        "mysql:host=${server};dbname=${name};charset=${charset}",
        $user, 
        $pass, 
        [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]
);

$user = new UserModel($conn); // dependency provided here
```

---

This example uses `PDO` as the dependency but the same can be applied for any object that provides an API or service. An example illustrating your point about...

> removal of hard-coded classes

would be something like

```
interface Foo {
    public function getFoo(): string;
}

class FooConsumer {
    public function __construct(Foo $foo) { // interface dependency defined here
        echo $foo->getFoo();
    }
}

class FooImpl implements Foo {
    public function getFoo(): string {
        return 'foo';
    }
}

$foo = new FooImpl();
$consumer = new FooConsumer($foo); // echos "foo"
```

Comment: So, in your first example, I wouldn't even need a seperate class in which I set the values of dbUser, dbPass etc.? Basically, instead of setting up a connection in a class and then extending other classes with the connection class and then performing the actions required with the database, I would set up other classes and connect to database in those classes?

Comment: @Mairis as I mentioned in my comment above, I'm not seeing much of a use for `DatabaseConfiguration` (at the moment). The main point I'm trying to make in my answer is that you ideally create only **one** `PDO` connection and pass it around where it's required. Creating connections in your consumer / client classes tightly couples the DB connection and your classes and also falls into the trap of possibly creating **multiple** connections

Comment: So basically - I just pass what i need through constructor and create objects outside the class bounds? That would mean that I don't need a seperate class for setting up all the options for database connection?

Comment: _"I just pass what i need through constructor and create objects outside the class bounds? "_ that's the general idea of DI, yes. _"That would mean that I don't need a seperate class for setting up all the options for database connection?"_ that depends. For example, a class that reads configuration from a file or similar data source might be very useful but if you're just hard-coding connection values, I don't see a reason for one.

Comment: Ok, now it finally makes some sort of sense to me. Thank you.